# Knowing if a post is sticky in the 'save_post' action. Where do I have to hook?

Tags: hooks, sticky-post

I'm using this plugin ([FantasticElasticSearch](https://github.com/parisholley/wordpress-fantastic-elasticsearch)) to index content when it's published. So far it was strightforward and an easy task but, now that I tried to index a flag saying if a post is sticky, I'm having trouble and it's being impossible.

I'm changing the addOrUpdate function of the plugin to my profit, I'm adding some data (featured image, featured video...) and as I said I want to index if a post is sticky. The problem is that the database is not updated in the index moment, and I don't know how to hook to that event.

This is what's happening now:

1. I publish a post, non-sticky.
2. I check if the post is sticky to add that information to the index, so far all is good and it's indexed well (as a non-sticky post is_sticky returns false).
3. I edit the post and turn it to an Sticky post. When I  check if the post is sticky it returns false again, as if it wasnt updated in the database yet.

So, where do I have to hook? Can I force the update of the database with the sticky/nonsticky information with some function?

The function (addOrUpdate) that I'm rewritting is the one that's in [this file](http://I'm%20rewritting%20the%20addOrUpdate%20function%20that%20there's%20in%20this%20file:%20[https://github.com/parisholley/wordpress-fantastic-elasticsearch/blob/master/src/elasticsearch/Indexer.php].).

I turned it into something like this:

```
static function addOrUpdate($post){
    $type = self::_index(true)->getType($post->post_type);
    $data = self::_build_document($post);

    //filling $data with extra fields I'd like to index
    $data['is_sticky'] = is_sticky();

    //now the document is added to elastic.
    $type->addDocument(new \Elastica\Document($post->ID, $data));       
}
```

The addOrUpdate function hooks into the save_post event as you can see [in the hooks.php](https://github.com/parisholley/wordpress-fantastic-elasticsearch/blob/master/wp/admin/hooks.php) file.

I'm still unable to get this working, I'd aprecciate any help you could give me on this matter. By the way, I already tried Pat J's method (is_sticky with Id post as a parameter, but I'm in the loop as I'm in the save_post action).

Finally solved it by looking in the $_POST array. $_POST['sticky'] is only informed when a POST is (**or is being made**) sticky.

Comment: Where is your code? Where/how are you checking for "is_sticky"?

Comment: I'm rewritting the addOrUpdate function that there's in this file: [https://github.com/parisholley/wordpress-fantastic-elasticsearch/blob/master/src/elasticsearch/Indexer.php]. I'll edit the post with more info.

Comment: Is this code run once, or does it run every time a post is updated?

Comment: Everytime a post is published/updated. It hooks into the save_post action.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I said in the question post, I finally solved it by looking into the $_POST global. There's a `$_POST['sticky']` field (valued as *'sticky'*) that is there just when a Post is *sticky* or is being made *sticky*, and it's not when a post is not *sticky* or is being *unsticked*.

Answer (score 0):

If you're not in The Loop, you should pass an ID to `is_sticky()`:

```
static function addOrUpdate($post){
    $type = self::_index(true)->getType($post->post_type);
    $data = self::_build_document($post);

    //filling $data with extra fields I'd like to index
    $data['is_sticky'] = is_sticky( $post->ID );

    //now the document is added to elastic.
    $type->addDocument(new \Elastica\Document($post->ID, $data));       
}
```

This assumes that the `$post` parameter you pass in is a [`WP_Post`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_post/) object.

#### Reference

- [`is_sticky()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/is_sticky/)

Comment: Yes, I should have said this but I've already tried. I even tried getting the sticky post ID's (get_option( 'sticky_posts' )) but the post was between the Ids when I tried to remove it and it wasn't when I tried to stick it.